# UITableView Section Titles Causing Table View Slowness

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` that loads entities from Core Data using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The fetch request is currently using a batch size to keep memory overhead under control as there are about 1000 rows being returned from the fetch. After hooking all this up, the table view was really fast.

My issue now comes from the fact that I want to add grouping and section titles to the table view. I've implemented the required delegate methods, but it seems that `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` is being called for every possible section in the fetch at load time. I am grouping by date so there are about 700 sections in the entire table view. As you might guess, this is slowing down the initial load of my view controller because it has to fetch through all the batches to get to my section titles. I was expecting this method to be called like the methods that load table view cells---as you scroll through the table.

Is there a better way to load the section titles or, better yet, is there a way to defer the loading of section titles to as the user scrolls like is done with the actual table cells?

Some things to note:

- I *am* telling the fetch request to pre-fault `dateOfFlight` using the `setPropertiesToFetch:` method.
- The fetch request has a batch limit of 25.
- The fetch request has no fetch limit.
- I do not need section index titles. For `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`, I am returning `Nil`;
- There are about 1000 entities returned from the fetch and, because we're grouping by a localized date, there are about 700 sections.

For what it's worth, here is the code I use to load the section title:

```
/**
 * We override this method from the base class because we need to format the date
 * prior to it being displayed in the UITableViewSection.
 * @author Jesse Bunch
 **/
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    Flight *cellEntity = (Flight *)[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (cellEntity) {
        return [cellEntity.dateOfFlight localizedLongDateString];
    }

    return L(@"Unknown Date");

}
```

-

### Edit

I did achieve a bit more speed by formatting the date from the section name rather than the entity itself:

```
/**
 * We override this method from the base class because we need to format the date
 * prior to it being displayed in the UITableViewSection.
 * @author Jesse Bunch
 **/
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    if(nil == dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ";
    }

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSDate *sectionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sectionInfo.name];  

    if (sectionDate) {
        return [sectionDate localizedLongDateString];
    }

    return L(@"Unknown Date");

}
```

Comment: Do [this tutorial on how to sort and group UITableView by date](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/) or [this Apple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) help?

Comment: The Apple example was an interesting approach, but it's not quite what I'm needing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about loading and displaying the data incrementally?

I mean: you load a bunch of data and display N rows (with N << 1000); if the user scrolls down past the last row, then more data is loaded and more rows displayed (and more sections).

I am not sure this approach could solve your issue (it might well be that after a number of pull-to-load, the view gets slow all the same) but I think you could give it a try... possibly, the user experience would also benefit from it (besides the slowness).

If you are interested, you can give a look at [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) which implements a similar mechanism for "pull down to reload". This could be useful for detecting the scroll past the last row.

Comment: I have thought about that and it is the route I'd probably like to go. However, I was wondering how I would go about telling the `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch more rows and add them on to the end of the data it's managing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with `NSFetchedResultsController`; I think, anyway that, if it does not support incremental or range-based fetch, you could execute the query and cache the results; then read them incrementally from the cache. About updating the table, you can use the methods listed under "Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections" in table view reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html.